# Bones not moving with the rest of the rig

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints

I have these bones in the front that are controlled by empty arrows. [image]

They move fine in the X axis.

[image]

But when moving the Z and Y axis they keep pointing forward
[image]

The arrows are parented to the main body rig as well

Comment: Hello could you please share your armature? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I figured it out thank you for trying to help tho <3.  I fixed it by changing the copy restraints mix to "add" and the owner to "Local with Parent"

Comment: Oh ok so maybe write your answer  ;)